# ZF2 return format based on accept header

Tags: php, http-headers, zend-framework2

In Zend Framework 2, I want to return JSON if the HTTP accept header is set to "application/json" and HTML otherwise. I am using the new `acceptableViewModelSelector` controller plugin just as in the [example in the 2.0.4 changelog](http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-0-4-released.html).

I have the following code:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {
    private $acceptCriteria = array(
        'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array('application/json'),
        'Zend\View\Model\FeedModel' => array('application/rss+xml')
    );

    public function jsonAcceptHeaderAction() {
        $view_model = $this->acceptableViewModelSelector($this->acceptCriteria);

        return $view_model;
    }
}
```

If I set the accept header like this:

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://mydomain.com/json`

Then the controller plugin returns a `JsonModel` instance as expected. However, it seems to *always* do this, even when there is no `application/json` in my accept header. For example, if I visit the page in Chrome, the following accept headers are sent:

`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`

I also get JSON back if I use `curl http://mydomain.com/json`. The controller plugin has a default view model name, which I expected it to use when it doesn't find a match with my accept criteria. The changelog says the following:

> The above would return a standard Zend\View\Model\ViewModel instance
>   if the criteria is not met, and the specified view model types if the
>   specific criteria is met.

I tried to change my accept criteria to the following, which turned out to do what I wanted.

```
private $acceptCriteria = array(
        'Zend\View\Model\ViewModel' => array('text/html'),
        'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array('application/json'),
        'Zend\View\Model\FeedModel' => array('application/rss+xml')
    );
```

I am just wondering why it does not use the default view model name when there is no `application/json` accept header, because ideally I would want to leave out the first entry in my accept criteria array.

Does anyone know why I always get a `JsonModel` object unless I do the change above?

Answer (score 0):

The default view model works, there is no issue with your code, if you don't have an **text/html** entry, if you access the url with any browser which is capable of accepting json, the accept criteria will match with the first entry i.e application/json.

To test the default model is working test your url with curl as below without the **text/html** entry in the acceptableviewmodel array, you will get the default view model output

```
curl -H "Accept: text/html" http://mydomain.com/json
```

This would return the default view model, so to work as you expect you need to have an entry **text/html**, place the entry in the array with your preferred order

Comment: How does the controller plugin know that my browser is capable of accepting JSON? Is it related to the `text/html` accept header, because JSON is text? If so, then I guess this should somehow be transparent in the source code of the controller plugin, but I don't recall seeing anything about it. Or is the `*/*` a wildcard, such that my browser will accept anything - kind of a fallback? I am still a little confused as to why it uses the `JsonModel` when I don't specify `application/json` in the accept header.